# R Programming: Save data with different space lengths

Tags: r

I am trying to use R to save the data to a specific format for another analysis software. For example, my data is:

```
Jane  2  3  0  1
Joe   2  0  1  1
John  1  0  0  0
Jack  2  1  3  1
Jay   0  0  0  0
```

I would like to save the data to a .txt file in the following format:

```
Jane  2301
Joe   2011
John  1000
Jack  2131
Jay   0000
```

If I used `write.table(....., sep = "")`, there will be no space between the names and numbers. How can I save the file with space only between the name and numbers? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
Jane  2  3  0  1
Joe   2  0  1  1
John  1  0  0  0
Jack  2  1  3  1
Jay   0  0  0  0

d <- read.table(con<-file("clipboard"), header = F)

d1 <- data.frame(col1 = d$V1, 
                 col2 = paste0(d$V2,d$V3,d$V4,d$V5))

write.table(d1, sep = " ", row.names = F)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to change the data format in R before saving it. Here, I am using `unite` from `tidyr` to push all of those columns together (it ignores just `V1` in this example, combining the rest)

Read sample data:

```
df <-
  read.table(
    text = 
"
Jane  2  3  0  1
Joe   2  0  1  1
John  1  0  0  0
Jack  2  1  3  1
Jay   0  0  0  0"
  )
```

Run `unite`

```
df %>%
  unite(singleData, -V1, sep = "")
```

Returns:

```
    V1 singleData
1 Jane       2301
2  Joe       2011
3 John       1000
4 Jack       2131
5  Jay       0000
```